# Vim unwrapping groups of lines in a file

Tags: regex, vim, text, formatting

For a text file in this general format (1000 +lines):

```
host hostname01.domain.org {
hardware ethernet aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff;
fixed-address 10.10.1.1;
 }

 host hostname02.domain.org {
hardware ethernet a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6;
fixed-address 10.10.1.2;
 }

 host hostname03.domain.org {
hardware ethernet 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f;
fixed-address 10.10.1.3;
 }
```

I'm looking to get to a hostname|MAC|ip format:

```
hostname01.domain.org|aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff|10.10.1.1
hostname02.domain.org|a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6|10.10.1.2
hostname03.domain.org|1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f|10.10.1.3
```

I tried these in vim (7.3, Mac OS 10.7.5).

```
:%s/\(.*host \)\(.*\) {/\2|/g
:%s/\(.*\)hardware ethernet \(.*\);/\2|/g
:%s/\(.*\)fixed-address \(.*\)\W/\2/g
:%s/.*}.*//g
```

At beginning of the first line(`gg`), record a macro `a` `qa3Jq`, then `:%norm! @a` to apply the macro to entire file, I get this instead, and other inconsistencies:

```
hostname01.domain.org|aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff|10.10.1.1 
hostname02.domain.org|a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6|10.10.1.2
hostname03.domain.org|
1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f|10.10.1.3
```

I think the macro is not doing what I think it is, or I'm not applying it correctly. How might I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this cmd a try:

```
%s/\v.*host +(\S*)\_.{-}net +([^;]*)\_.{-}ress +([^;]*)\_.{-}\}\n\n?/\1|\2|\3\r/g
```

macro is also possible, but if the data had different fmt, like trailing spaces, leading spaces or more spaces between words/WORDs, it could fail.

Comment: Nice! Could you explain what `{-}` does? And `\_.` -- is that "match a newline"?

Comment: @KM. `:h \_.` and `:h /\{` you will find the explanations

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro:

```
"q   {^Mv%J0df f vf:F c|^[f;vf;F c|^[f;D0j
```

It works for your example data (`^M` is return, `^[` is Escape). But most probably, what you really need is a script that does the work; Perl, Python or ViM-Script come to mind.

Comment: Mm, looks like I have too much variation in my data with spaces and newlines that this does not work well, sadly.

Comment: I guess a macro will be a bad choice then -- I'd write a small program for such tasks, most probably in Perl.